# how to merge specfic file using svn command

Tags: svn

Is there any way to merge a specific set of extesnion using merge command between two branches
eg:- i want to merge only ".jsp" extension or any extension of my choice

```
svn merge https://www.test.com/branches/a1/*.jsp  https://www.test.com/branches/a2/*.jsp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a local copy, then you can write a shell command with a `for` loop to issue a separate `svn merge` for each file, something like

```
for i in *.jsp; do
    svn merge https://www.test.com/branches/a1/$i  https://www.test.com/branches/a2/$i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just merge everything to your working copy, then revert every modified/added/removed file that is not a .jsp file, and commit.